# HTML local file access

Tags: html, file, path, reference, local

I would like to access a local file in the immediate directory

From my understanding, you'd usually have to do something like

```
file://path/to/file/document.html
```

which requires the full path, but I would like to do something like

```
file://./document.html
```

instead, where `./` represents the current directory reference, so that I do not have to know the directory path nor make any assumptions about it.

is there any trickery like that possible with html file paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
document.html
```

With no protocol specified, and no `/` for directories, the browser should request the asset from the same directory/folder that the current page is at.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.nt22.com/html_tutorials/022_html_path.html

using page.html and ./page.html works the same.

../ goes to a lower directory
i.e.

root/www/page.html

if you are in root/stuff/hi.html you can go to the 'www' directory by doing
../www/page.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @gnat This post was posted a while ago when I first joined. I have learned my lesson, but I guess I didn't bother saying what's useful in it.

Am I replying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If it's running locally (from that directory), just use `./` without the `file://`.